# How to implement equals for generic pairs?

Tags: java, generics, equals, type-systems

Just for fun, I'm trying to implement a generic Pair class in Java. I'm having trouble with `equals`:

```
public class Pair<A, B>
{
    public final A _1;
    public final B _2;

    // ... unnecessary details left out ...

    public boolean equals(Pair<A, B> that)
    {
        return (_1.equals(that._1)) && (_2.equals(that._2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        return (o instanceof Pair<A, B>) && equals((Pair<A, B>) o);
    }
}
```

However, `o instanceof Pair<A, B>` does not seem to work. Why is that?

Using `(o instanceof Pair) && equals((Pair<A, B>) o)` gives me a warning for the cast. Getting rid of the `<A, B>` part on the cast still gives me a warning, which I guess also some sense.

Does that mean Java cannot prevent clients from comparing Pairs with different type arguments?

Comment: Aren't you simply asking how to use `instanceof` with paremetrized types?

Comment: I think this should work, as long as the `A` and `B` have well-behaved `equals()` methods, which should verify that their classes are compatible.  The problem is that the `A` and `B` types are erased at runtime, essentially getting reduced to `Object` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does that mean Java cannot prevent clients from comparing Pairs with different type arguments?

Yes, but that's the point -- `equals` should work with any arbitrary object.  What you want would look like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (o instanceof Pair) {
       Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;
       return _1.equals(pair._1) && _2.equals(pair._2);
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this should be fine, as long as `A` and `B` have proper implementations of `equals` that take arbitrary `Object`s.

Comment: But you don't use the `pair` that you cast from `o`

Comment: @Cratylus `pair` and `that` are probably two names for the same variable ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `instanceof` like you do due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You can only check for `instanceof Pair`.
Also what is up with that `_1` and `_2`? Really?

Comment: `_1` and `_2` are idiomatic names for pair members in functional programming languages.

Comment: @FredOverlow:I suspected that.But it is unconventional to use in `Java`.

Comment: In that case: `"idiomatic names".replace("ma", "")` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
o instanceof Pair<A, B>
```

does not work because generics are not there at runtime, therefore `instanceof` is not aware of them.