# How do I implement equals for generic types?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Suppose I have a generic container type like this:

```
public final class Container<T> {

    public final T t;

    public Container(final T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

I want to implement equals such that this passes:

```
final Container<Object> a = new Container<>("Hello");
final Container<String> b = new Container<>("Hello");

assertNotEquals(a, b);
```

The instances `a` and `b` should be different because their type parameter `T` is different.

However, due to erasure, this is tricky to do. This implementation, for example, is incorrect:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj != null && obj instanceof Container<?>) {
        final Container<?> other = (Container<?>)obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.t, other.t);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I expect that I will need to store some kind of token for `T`.

How do I implement equals for generic types?

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957729/how-to-implement-equals-for-generic-pairs) does not answer the question.

Comment: It really has nothing to do with erasure. If you use arrays, where there is no erasure, like `Object[] a = { "Hello" }; String[] b = { "Hello" };`, `a[0].equals(b[0])` would still return `true`. The `equals` operation uses the object's runtime types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can modify a little the Container class and add this field:

```
public final Class<T> ct;
```

with that and the equals override then

```
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

will return `false` because the equals method will check `Class<String>` vs `Class<Object>`

```
class Container<T> {

    public final T t;
    public final Class<T> ct;

    public Container(final T t, Class<T> ct) {
        this.t = t;
        this.ct = ct;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = (prime * result) + ((ct == null) ? 0 : ct.hashCode());
        result = (prime * result) + ((t == null) ? 0 : t.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Container other = (Container) obj;
        if (ct == null) {
            if (other.ct != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ct.equals(other.ct))
            return false;
        if (t == null) {
            if (other.t != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!t.equals(other.t))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate the boiler-plate of `new Container<String>("a", String.class)`? Will this still work for `Container<Container<String>>`?

Comment: You should acquaint yourself with `Objects.hash()`, which does exactly what your implementation of `hashCode()` does, so your method becomes just `return Objects.hash(ct, t);`